# ошибка при объявление let = Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript

Есть два варианта строки.

первая выдает: a = 1 + 2, 3 + 4 // 3

вторая с ошибкой: let a = 1 + 2, 3 + 4 // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при let такой результат и почему тогда работает необъявленная переменная?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что существует синтаксис:

```
let a = 1, b = 2
```

А в первом случае, нет декларации, это оператор запятая, разделяющий 2 выражения:

```
(a = 1 + 2), (3 + 4)
```

`3 + 4` можно просто удалить, оно не используется.
Хотя, как раз оно и является результатом всего выражения:

```js
console.log((a = 1 + 2, 3 + 4)) // 7
console.log(a) // 3
```